# Kubuntu 22.04 - 2nd monitor screen flickering

Tags: multiple-monitors

I am running dual monitors. My laptop monitor is fine but my second monitor is flickering and ghosting. I have tried everything I can find online but I cant fix it.

Is it possible I can fix the issue by trying a different distro? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

You write that you tried all possible settings. What is your resolution and frame rate on an external monitor?

If you have a 2K or 4K external monitor at 60 fps or more, try replacing the cable. Use "High Speed" HDMI cable only. Old HDMI cables version 1.1 or 1.2 do terrible things with images having resolutions of 1440p and higher.

Comment: The frame rate is 60hz and the resolution is 1920x1080. It works fine on windows. The cable is heavy duty,

Comment: I Upgraded to 22.10 and the issue is fixed.